# Adding noise to a PIL or numpy image with numpy/pytorch

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, computer-vision, pytorch

I'm trying to reproduce this interesting paper: "Deep Image Prior".
https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.10925

Now, I saw there is a colab version that I can run and it works pretty nice:
[DIP](https://colab.research.google.com/github/DmitryUlyanov/deep-image-prior)

The only think missing for me is this graph:
[image]

Now, I think I found the place in the code where this process is taking place:
[DIP restoration](https://colab.research.google.com/github/DmitryUlyanov/deep-image-prior/blob/master/restoration.ipynb)

Where is the noise addition?

Edit:
The noise addition happens here:

> #### Main loop
>
> ```py
> def closure():
>
>    global i, psrn_masked_last, last_net, net_input
>    
>    if reg_noise_std > 0:
>        net_input = net_input_saved + (noise.normal_() * reg_noise_std)
> ```

Why, if I remark these lines I still see a noised image being plotted?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The noise addition happens here:

> #### Main loop
>
> ```py
> def closure():
>
>    global i, psrn_masked_last, last_net, net_input
>    
>    if reg_noise_std > 0:
>        net_input = net_input_saved + (noise.normal_() * reg_noise_std)
> ```

Comment: Yes you're right, my mistake.

But lets get back to the original question for a moment:
If I want to emulate that graph, how can I do that?
How can I added these type of noises (U(0,1), image shuffle, and white noise) on pytorch? 

And what's the best way to collect the data and plot it as a graph, just like on the image.

Thanks a lot for your help!